# Is that possible to to change keybroadType in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, keyboard

My app is blog editor app using uiwebview( using js, css..). Problem met when i want to change keyboard from default ( text) to Phone Pad. Googling I know a way to use  but not help my case.

Is that possible to change keyboard type like `UITextView`, `UITextField`

```
// textField is set to a UIKeyboardType other than UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress
[textField setKeyboardType: UIKeyboardTypePhonePad];
[textField reloadInputViews];
```

Maybe subclass `UIWebView` to custom like
[UIWebView+GUIFixes](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Editor-iOS/blob/9812b6c9a699cd654ef5c0cffe9bed9f91c06782/Classes/UIWebView%2BGUIFixes.m)

Thank for advance!

Comment: if ur using search as uitextfield means it is possible

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set keyboard type for UIWebview. 
It can be achieved by setting input element type used in web page.

```
<input type="text"> 
<input type="tel">
```